# how to find backup history of SSAS database

Tags: sql-server, backup, ssas

Shockingly on Internet, I am unable to find backup history of SSAS database.

Is there no way to do it?

Also should we take multiple backups of SSAS database? I am not much aware of SSAS database.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no dynamic management view(DMV) available to get this backup history details about SSAS database. You can get these [details](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/13faf8dd-a392-4dee-8712-48de041227ff/ssas-database-backup-history?forum=sqlanalysisservices) by using below method:

1. Implement this backup process with SSIS either using XMLA or SSIS task
2. Use to implement the logging and completion of backup task time to a log table.

*Unlike a relational database backup file, an SSAS backup file can contain only one backup. In other words, you can’t create backup sets. If you want to retain multiple backups, you must create multiple files. Also, SSAS doesn’t provide options for differential backups or log file backups.*

By default, two check boxes are selected in the Backup Database window -  Apply compression and Encrypt backup file. When the Apply compression option is selected, SSAS compresses the backup file, which saves disk space at the expense of higher CPU utilization during the backup operation. When the Encrypt backup file option is selected, SSAS accepts a user-supplied password, which it uses to encrypt the backup file. Note that, unlike the password for a SQL Server relational database backup set, this password prevents the reading of the backup data by other means. If you choose to encrypt SSAS backups, make sure that you keep a record of the password in a safe and separate location. More details are [here](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/backup-basics-sql-server-analysis-services), [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/backup-and-restore-of-analysis-services-databases?view=asallproducts-allversions) and [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3614/sql-server-analysis-services-backup-and-restore/).

Script for XMLA and using ascmd.exe is mentioned at this [link](http://www.ssas-info.com/analysis-services-scripts/2679-script-to-backup-ssas-database-and-delete-old-backup-files).

Hope above helps.

Answer (score 0):

> should we take multiple backups of SSAS database?

Backups are essential, but I don't think more frequent backups (like OLTP database) are not necessary for SSAS unless it fall under anyone of following...

- MOLAP or Tabular with Import mode source data within SSAS is valuable, takes longer time to refresh entire model/cube
- Frequent changes happens within the SSAS objects (Cube/Model)
- To recover SSAS objects with particular point in time

Because main use of SSAS backups is migration (moving SSAS DB into different server), to recover meta data, aggregations, and objects within SSAS. Not to recover actual source data. Thus, without being source data recoverable there is no use of SSAS backups, and always SSAS data must be protected in source level i.e. SQL DB (any other OLTP DB) or Data-warehouse with point in recovery option.

[Further reading...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/backup-and-restore-of-analysis-services-databases?view=asallproducts-allversions#bkmk_cube)